# define a parameter in event

Tags: c#, button, event-handling

I have a TableLayoutPanel (tlp) with rows. I add rows manually with a button. Every row which I created below the last one, has a button that will remove the row from tlp. Here is the code:

```
    private void btnTSatirEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tlpTDersRows = tlpTDers.RowCount;

        tlpTDers.RowCount++;

        DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
        dtp.Name = "dtpTR" + (tlpTDersRows).ToString();
        DateTimePicker dtp2 = (DateTimePicker)tlpTDers.Controls["dtpTR" + (tlpTDersRows - 1).ToString()];
        dtp.Value = dtp2.Value.AddDays(1);
        dtp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tlpTDers.Controls.Add(dtp, 0, tlpTDersRows);

        ComboBox comb = new ComboBox();
        comb.Name = "cbxTR" + (tlpTDersRows).ToString();
        comb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        comb.Items.AddRange(devamDur);
        tlpTDers.Controls.Add(comb, 1, tlpTDersRows);

        TextBox txtr = new TextBox();
        txtr.Name = "txtTR" + (tlpTDersRows).ToString();
        txtr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        txtr.Multiline = true;
        tlpTDers.Controls.Add(txtr, 2, tlpTDersRows);

        oldX = btnTSatirEkle.Location.X;
        oldY = btnTSatirEkle.Location.Y;

        Button buttonNew = new Button();
        buttonNew.Name = "btnDelTR" + (tlpTDersRows - 1).ToString();
        buttonNew.Text = "-";
        buttonNew.Location = new Point(oldX, oldY);
        buttonNew.Size = btnTSatirEkle.Size;
        this.Controls.Add(buttonNew);
        buttonNew.Click += new EventHandler(SatirSil);  //I get error here, even I write SatirSil(sender, e, tlpTDersRows - 1)..

        btnTSatirEkle.Location = new Point(644, tlpTDers.Controls["dtpTR" + tlpTDersRows.ToString()].Location.Y + 12);

        tlpTDersRows++;
    }

    private void SatirSil(object sender, EventArgs e, int rowNo)
    {
       //codes
    }
```

I want to send the row number as parameter to SatirSil method (which will be called when I click on buttonNew_Click event).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
buttonNew.Click += new EventHandler(SatirSil);
```

to

```
buttonNew.Click += new EventHandler((snd, ev)=>SatirSil(snd,ev,rowno));
```

or using your own variable (i.e. `tlpTDersRows`) it could be like this:

```
buttonNew.Click += new EventHandler((snd, ev)=>SatirSil(snd,ev,tlpTDersRows-1));
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get an error about (sender, e).. full message like: A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else..

Comment: @SertanPekel Try changing the word sender to snd for example. I'll update my code.

Comment: @SertanPekel the sender and e actually conflicts with the sender which is inside the parameter of btnTSatirEkle_Click where the event is initialized. So, that's why you have to change its name to something else so that it would not conflict. In this case I am using snd for sender and ev for event to prevent the conflict.

Comment: Glad that it work for you @SertanPekel. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Button.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) event is defined as

```
public event EventHandler Click
```

where `EventHandler` is defined by

```
public delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
```

This means that for a method to be assignable as a handler for an event, it must have the exact signature defined by a delegate, i.e. it must take two parameters, an `object` and an `EventArgs` instance, and it must return `void`. The signature of your `SatirSil` method

```
void SatirSil(object sender, EventArgs e, int rowNo)
```

does not match, because it has an additional integer parameter. As mentioned in the other answers, you have two common solutions to this problem:

- Somehow embed the extra parameter in the `sender` parameter, because the `EventArgs` by itself is pretty much useless. Since most of the time the sender parameter will in fact be a `Control` object, it is common to use the [`Control.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property to store extra data about the sender, that will be taken out by the handler and used as required. That will look like:

  ```
  Button buttonNew = new Button();
  ...
  buttonNew.Tag = (tlpTDersRows - 1);
  buttonNew.Click = SatirSil;
  ....
  void SatirSil(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     int rowNumber = (int)(sender as Control).Tag;
     //rest of code
  }
  ```
- Somehow create a specialized version of the handler that will have the row number "hardcoded". Starting from C# 3.0 this is relatively easy to accomplish using the lambda syntax, that generates an inline "method" for you, e.g.

  ```
  EventHandler handler = (sender, e) => {...code here ...}
  ```

  is code that creates a delegate instance called "handler" that you can attach to an event, using

  ```
  someButton.Click += handler;
  ```

  or you can even invoke, using

  ```
  handler(senderValue, eValue);
  ```

  Note that the "...code here..." block is still contained in the original method where you write the declaration, so whatever is accessible to the method, is accessible to the body of the lambda expression. Knowing that you can make a separate handler for each button using code like:

  ```
  Button buttonNew = new Button();
  ...
  buttonNew.Click = (_, __) => SatirSil(rowNumber);
  //if you do not care about parameters, 
  //it's customary to use _, __,  etc for the names
  //instead of the more verbose
  //buttonNew.Click = (sender, e) => SatirSil(rowNumber);
  ....
  void SatirSil(int rowNumber)
  {
     //actual implementation
  }
  ```

I personally prefer the second option, because it neatly separated the code that is concerned with the creation and wire-up of the button, from the code that does the actual work. For example, if the `SatirSil` method was needed in another part of the code, the calls would respectively be:

```
Control dummy = new Control();
dummy.Tag = myRowNumber;
SatirSil(dummy, null);
```

vs

```
SatirSil(myRowNumber);
```

Comment: I solved the case by @Edper's solution, but your answer contains a lot of information that might be useful for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I got one idea:

```
buttonNew.Click += new EventHandler((sender,args)=>SatirSil(sender,args,rowNo));
```

This way you'll still be setting `buttonNew.Click` with a compatible `EventHandler`, but the body of the anonymous method will be using your method `SatirSil` which uses your row number as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The button is the `sender` of your event. So if you store your row number in the `Tag` property of your button, like so:

```
buttonNew.Tag = tlpTDersRows;
```

you could then do something like:

```
private void SatirSil(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    int rowNo = (int)button.Tag;
    // ... delete row here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Button buttonNew = new Button();
buttonNew.Name = "btnDelTR" + (tlpTDersRows - 1).ToString();
buttonNew.Text = "-";
buttonNew.Location = new Point(oldX, oldY);
buttonNew.Size = btnTSatirEkle.Size;
this.Controls.Add(buttonNew);
buttonNew.Tag = tlpTDersRows - 1;
buttonNew.Click += SatirSil;

private void SatirSil(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //codes
   var btn = (Button)sender;
   var row = (int)btn.Tag;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can modify the delgate signature for Button click event which was defined already. If you do what you're trying to do then you will get compiler error.
How you can achieve in other way is while creating the button name , append it with the row number , so that in the event handler you can cast the sender object to button and get the name and extract the row number from it.

```
    buttonNew.Name = "btnDelTR_" + rowNumber

    private void SatirSil(object sender, EventArgs e, int rowNo)
    {
             int rowNo =   //split the string to get the number.
    }
```